# Error running lumen api on docker (reason: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known)

Tags: php, laravel, docker, dockerfile, lumen

I'm trying to run a very simple lumen api on docker (https://github.com/alves-nathan/covidprudente).
The build goes ok, but trying to run the image returns the error:

```
Failed to listen on  localhost:8001 (reason: php_network_getaddresses:
getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known)

Warning: Unknown: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
Name or service not known in Unknown on line 0
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN chmod o+r /etc/resolv.conf

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

ENV HOME=/home/app
COPY ./ $HOME/codivpp/

COPY --chown=www:www ./ $HOME/codivpp/

USER www
WORKDIR $HOME/covidpp

EXPOSE 8001

CMD ["php", "-S localhost:8001 -t public"]
```

I'm still beginner on docker so I don't know what I'm missing.

Other (maybe) usefull info:

```
Docker version 19.03.11, build 42e35e61f3
```

Comment: Try `0.0.0.0:8001` instead of `localhost:8001`

Comment: now the error changed to Failed to listen on  0.0.0.0:8001 as well. :(

Comment: managed to make the "run" work by changing the last line to CMD ["php", "-S", "0.0.0.0:8001", "-t", "public"], however I cant access it on my browser: This site can’t be reached The connection was reset.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add localhost to your hosts file. That error means that `localhost` does not exists.

Also, we would really need to see how your nginx & docker composer is setup.

Comment: I'm not using nginx and i'm building and trying to run the image via terminal with the following commands: docker build --network=host --tag covidpp:1.0 . and docker run -p 8001:8001 covidpp:1.0 and i'm trying to serve the application directly via php with  CMD ["php", "-S localhost(now 0.0.0.0):8001 -t public"]